# Normalization with LASSO regression in caret package returns strange results

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, normalization, r-caret

I normalized my [data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/) using min-max normalization. Then I used the `train` function in the `caret` package to build the LASSO regression.

```
data <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/forestfires.csv") 
data<-data[-(3:4)]  #remove catogrical variables

normalize <- function(x) {
  return ((x-min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}
data <- as.data.frame(lapply(data, normalize))

lambda.grid <-10^seq(10,-2, length =100)
alpha.grid<- 1 #Lasso

control <- trainControl(method="LOOCV")
srchGrd = expand.grid(alpha = alpha.grid, lambda = lambda.grid)
lm_model <- train(area ~ . , data=data, trControl=control,tuneGrid=srchGrd,method = 'glmnet')
```

I got the follwoing result

```
lambda        RMSE        Rsquared  MAE       
  1.000000e-02  0.05841138  1         0.01705366
  1.321941e-02  0.05841138  1         0.01705366
  1.747528e-02  0.05841138  1         0.01705366
  2.310130e-02  0.05841138  1         0.01705366
  3.053856e-02  0.05841138  1         0.01705366
.
.
.
```

The R-square is always equal to one and RMSE has the same value!

***NOTE***

I know that we can use the `preProcess` function to normalized the data but it gives me the same results. Is there a specific grid for lambda or not. since I would not like to use cv.glmnet. Should I make lambda grid the same for ridge and lasso regression?

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: You should be able to see different values if you include much smaller values in `lambda.grid`.  For the present values, it seems the best model is the intercept (for all values of lambda searched.)

Comment: Sorry, I am sure how to select the range of values for `lambda.grid`.

Comment: Try `lambda.grid <-10^seq(-2, -10, length =100)`

Comment: @January, many thanks, but is there a rule for choosing lambda value? because every time I change the values or even the length of lambda, I got different results!

Comment: @January, why not for example `lambda.grid <-10^seq(-10, 10, length= 100)`

Comment: The results should not be different for a given alpha and lambda. Although, to be frank, I know these regression models only superficially.  However, I looked a bit at the data set and I don't think it is an easy data set to work with. I have seen it fail with DNN. I tried my favorite approaches (random forests, pca) and I could not get any reasonable predictions.  I think you should get your method going first and gather experience with data sets which have stronger signals.

Comment: See [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/forest+fires) for more information about this data set.

Comment: @January, I know about this data but I have to work with it. Also, I mean each time I run the model with a diffrent grid of lambda I got different results. So this why I am a bit confused about which the grid lambda value to choose.

Comment: Do you really get different results for identical alpha and lambda combination? I was not able to repeat this behavior.

Comment: @January, I held an alpha constant at 1 since I am dealing with LASSO. Then when I run the model with for example `lambda.grid <-10^seq(-2, -10, length =100)` I got different of RMSE and R-squared when I used `lambda.grid <-10^seq(-10, 10, length= 100)`. Do you get my idea now?

Comment: No, you are *not* getting different RMSE and R-squared for the given values of lambda. Please look more carefully at what I wrote and what your output is. Frankly, at that point I am a little bit tired. For example, in these two sequences of lambdas, you have a lambda of approximately 2.656088e-08. You will find that independent of what other lambdas are, this particular lambda will get RMSE=0.05853143 and Rsquared=0.003553788.